# How to import nested files with @testable import in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, unit-testing

I'm currently working in a Swift project and am starting to create some unit tests for the Model classes that I created.

The project file hierarchy is: 
<Project>
*<Group A> (Name contains spaces) 
**<Models> (All my models that I want to test are located here
*<Test Group> 
**<ModelTests> (All my tests for the models are located here)

At the moment, I have `@testable import Group_A` in my tests, but every time I try to make an object of a type in my Models folder, I get a `Use of unresolved type identifier: '&lt;TYPE>'`

Comment: Make sure to select Enable Testability in your project target's build settings.

Comment: @MikeTaverne, sorry for the delay in my response. The project already had Enable Testability enabled, so that doesn't seem to be the answer. <Group A> and <Test Group> are groups inside of a single project, so there shouldn't be a lack of communication in regards to inter-project settings.

Comment: You could try renaming Group A to remove the space, or add a GroupB, to see if the space is the problem.

Comment: I found the problem. The test classes couldn't reading into the Models folder, which was an actual file in the folder hierarchy, not just a Group in xcode. By moving the model files out of the models folder, the tests were able to find the models.